# QGIS 3.16.3 uses Python 3.7.7 while I want it to use Python 3.9.1 already on my MacOS Big Sur

Tags: qgis, python, raster, vector, macos

> ```
> MacOS: Big Sur 11.1
> QGIS: 3.16.3
> ```

KyngChaos said that QGIS 3.16 is using Python 3.9.X (strictly) and I installed this in my system, however the Python bundled with QGIS is 3.7.7. It is strange that the correct version is not bundled or supplied with QGIS itself.

I would like to know how I can change the Python from 3.7.7 to 3.9.1 in QGIS?

Comment: Look at  [Introducing new QGIS macOS packages](https://blog.qgis.org/2019/07/29/introducing-new-qgis-macos-packages/). Now all dependencies (Python, GDAL, etc)  are bundled within the disk image